# How to store data into MongoDB as integer instead of string in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Using Nodejs, Express I  want to store data into Database as integer and find the Mean. Currently, the data(both name and Campus) is stored as String and When $avg is used to find average the db returns null value. The tables in the database are Name and Campus. The name must String and Campus must be an integer. The $avg is performed on Campus with Same Names.
This is my server.js File

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://dbname:passw@d1111.mlab.com:11111/rank', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on 8080')
  })
})

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('colleges').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('index.ejs', {colleges: result})
  })
})

app.get('/answers', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('colleges').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('index.ejs', {colleges: result})
  })
})


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extender: true}))


app.post('/colleges', (req, res) =>{
    db.collection('colleges').save(req.body, (err, result) =>{
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        console.log('saved to database')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))

        res.redirect('/')
    })
})
```

This is my index.ejs file has this form

```
<form action="/colleges" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
  <input type="number" placeholder="campus" name="campus">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Code to Calculate average

```
db.colleges.aggregate([
           { $match: { college: "RVCE"}}, 
           { $group: {_id:"campus", total: {$avg: "$campus"}}}
           ])
```

Comment: Where is the code that stores the data? Where is the code that performs the `$avg` query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply do this i guess,

```
app.post('/colleges', (req, res) =>{
req.body.campus = parseInt(req.body.campus);
db.collection('colleges').save(req.body, (err, result) =>{
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))

    res.redirect('/')
});
```